# Is there any way on Tkinter that when I plot a new graph on a canvas, the previous one is destroyed and not stacked on the right?

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there any way that when I plot a new graph on a canvas, the previous one is destroyed and not stacked on the right? I tried some stuff like using a `.destroy()` but nothing seems work... It keeps putting new graph to the right every time I hit <kbd>draw</kbd> button. I have no idea how to solve it so any help its really welcome.

Here is a picture of what happens when I press the button: another graph is added to the right. I just want only one (the last one that I get when button pressed).

[image]

[image]

Here is my code:

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="draw",command=lambda:  func1())
        button2.pack()
        entry1 = Entry(self,width = 20)
        entry1.pack()
        entry2 = Entry(self,width = 20)
        entry2.pack()
        entry3 = Entry(self,width = 20)
        entry3.pack()

        def func1():
            rho = float(entry1.get())
            sigma = float(entry2.get())
            beta = float(entry3.get())
            def f(state, t):
                x, y, z = state  
                return sigma * y, z-sigma, rho*x * y - beta * z  

            state0 = [4.0, 3.0, 2.0]
            t = np.arange(0.0, 40.0, 0.01)

            states = odeint(f, state0, t)

            fig = plt.figure()
            canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self)
            canvas.draw() 
            ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
            ax.plot(states[:, 0], states[:, 1], states[:, 2])
            canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.LEFT,fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
```

Comment: I think you can't destroy canvas because you are using canvas as a local variable of the function `func1`. Try again using `self.canvas` instead. If it doesn't work tell me and I will take a better look on that

Answer (score 0):

You can create the `fig` and `canvas` outside `func1()` and update the figure inside it:

```py
class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="draw",command=lambda: func1())
        button2.pack()
        entry1 = tk.Entry(self, width=20)
        entry1.pack()
        entry2 = tk.Entry(self, width=20)
        entry2.pack()
        entry3 = tk.Entry(self, width=20)
        entry3.pack()

        fig = plt.figure()
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self)

        def func1():
            rho = float(entry1.get())
            sigma = float(entry2.get())
            beta = float(entry3.get())
            def f(state, t):
                x, y, z = state  
                return sigma * y, z-sigma, rho*x * y - beta * z  

            state0 = [4.0, 3.0, 2.0]
            t = np.arange(0.0, 40.0, 0.01)

            states = odeint(f, state0, t)

            plt.clf()  # clear current figure
            ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
            ax.plot(states[:, 0], states[:, 1], states[:, 2])
            canvas.draw() # update the figure
            canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
```